# Yum through http proxy

Tags: yum

I have several Fedora 13 servers that have to connect through an http proxy for yum updates. All port 80 traffic has to be routed through this proxy. I have setup the proxy server in the network settings GUI. I can browse the internet just fine. I have also setup my proxy information in /etc/yum.conf as follows:
proxy=http:proxy.largecorp.corp/accelerated_pac_base.pac
proxy_user=user
proxy_password=password

I then added the export HTTP_PROXY="http:proxy.largecorp.corp/accelerated_pac_base.pac" to /etc/bashrc and sourced the file.

When i run yum update:
Loaded plugins:presto, refresh-packagekit
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) fro repository: fedora. Please verify its path and try again.

All of the repo urls are the defaults, as this is a fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

Use ntlmaps proxy. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntlmaps/ configure it, run it (you need python on your box) and put something like

```
http://127.0.0.1:5865
```

in your yum.conf (port number may be different, depending on your configuration).

Answer (score 1):

`http:proxy.largecorp.corp/accelerated_pac_base.pac` is not a valid URL, shouldn't it be `http://proxy.largecorp.corp/accelerated_pac_base.pac`?

Apart from this, you should try to explicitely state which proxy yum needs to use, instead of pointing it to an auto-configuration URL like the one you're using; something like

```
http://proxy.largecorp.corp:8080
```

Just look up your actual proxy settings and use them.

Comment: That was a typo on my part.